# Update Lookup Value by Trigger

Tags: triggers, apex

I have a custom object(custom_object__c) which contain lookup with a user,
and I have a lookup to the custom_object__c from Opportunity, now I need to fill the custom_object__c lookup if the user lookup field present in the custom_object__c is equal to Opportunity Owner and Opportunity Stage equals Prospecting.

My code below:

trigger Update_Approver_Target on Opportunity (before insert, before Update) {

```
Set<id> appIds = new Set<id>();
Map<id, Approver_Target__c> appsMap = new Map<id, Approver_Target__c>([SELECT Name, User__c FROM Approver_Target__c WHERE Id IN :appIds]);
for (Opportunity opp : Trigger.new)
    appIds.add(opp.Approver_Target__c);

for (Opportunity opp : Trigger.new) {

    System.debug('Opportunity: '+appsMap.get(opp.Approver_Target__c).User__c);
    if(opp.OwnerId == opp.Approver_Target__r.User__c && opp.StageName == 'Prospecting'){

        opp.Approver_Target__c = opp.Approver_Target__r.Name;
    }
    else{

        opp.Approver_Target__c = '';
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Hello Heisenberg, Can you specifically mention your question and issue? Any error while developing this trigger?

Comment: I didn't have any error at the same time it's not working... and the question I mentioned above the code.